# Stuck finding the sum of two series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

This is the first time I ever make a post on Stack Exchange (and the last time I stop lurking it!), so apologies in advance if I caused any problems.

I am completely stuck at finding the sum of the two following series:

$$\sum_{n=1}^∞(2n+1)x^n$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^∞\frac{x^n}{(n+1)2^n}$$

I understand that I should be using this series to find out their value: $$\sum_{n=0}^∞x^n=\frac{1}{1-x}$$

I already used it for a couple of simpler series, but I cannot get my head around the two ones above

Comment: Be careful with your lower limits! What you need here (in conjunction with @DonAntonio's answer) is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n$, not $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Set $f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (2n+1)x^n$. Then 
   $$
   f(t^2) 
   = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (2n+1)t^{2n} 
   = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{d}{dt}t^{2n+1}
   = \frac{d}{dt} \sum_{n=1}^\infty t^{2n+1}
   = \frac{d}{dt} \left( t \sum_{n=1}^\infty (t^2)^n \right)
   = \frac{d}{dt} \left( \frac{t^3}{1-t^2} \right) \\
   = \frac{3t^2(1-t^2)-t^3(-2t)}{(1-t^2)^2}
   = \frac{3t^2-t^4}{(1-t^2)^2}.
   $$
   Thus,
   $$
   f(x) = \frac{3x-x^2}{(1-x)^2}.
   $$
2. Set $g(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{(n+1)2^n}.$ Then,
   $$
   \frac{d}{dx} \left( x \, g(x) \right) 
   = \frac{d}{dx} \left( 2 \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(x/2)^{n+1}}{(n+1)} \right)
   = 2 \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2} (x/2)^n
   = \frac{1}{1-x/2}
   = \frac{2}{2-x}.
   $$
   Therefore, for some constant $C$,
   $$x \, g(x) = C - 2 \ln(2-x).$$
   The constant can be determined by $0 = 0 \, g(0) = C - 2 \ln 2,$ i.e. $C = 2 \ln 2.$
   Thus,
   $$g(x) = \frac{2 \ln 2}{x} - 2 \frac{\ln(2-x)}{x} = 2 \frac{\ln 2 - \ln(2-x)}{x} = 2 \frac{\ln(2/(2-x))}{x}.$$

Comment: Thank you! Now I got it.

Answer (score 0):

For example:

$$\frac1{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n\implies \frac1{(1-x)^2}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{n-1}\implies\frac x{(1-x)^2}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^n\;,\;\;|x|<1$$

and now do some calculations with $\;(2n+1)x^n=2nx^n+x^n\;$, with the help of arithmetic of series (limits)

For the other one integrate:

$$\frac1{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n\implies -\log(1-x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}\;,\;\;|x|<1$$

You may also want to consider $\;\frac x2\;$ in the last part...

Comment: Thanks! Though I still don't quite understand it: For the 1st, what do you mean by the "arithmetic of series(limits)"? We haven't seen limits in power series so far, only for calculating the radius of convergence. For the 2nd one, then I would need to play with 1/(x*2^n) * −log(1−x) = $$\sum_{n=0}^∞\frac{x^n}{(n+1)2^n}$$? I don't know how to advance from there.

Comment: But I think you may have seen that sum  of convergent series is convergent, so $\;\sum(a_n+b_n)=\sum a_n+\sum b_n;$ when each series separately converges. That what I meant. For the second one check the series with $\;\frac x2\;$ instead, meaning: $$-\log(1-2x)=\sum\frac{\left(\frac x2\right)^{n+1}}{{n+1}}\;\ldots$$

Comment: You might have mentioned that what you are doing in the first line is differentiating...

Comment: @TonyK Perhaps, but if the OP can't figure out that by himself then maybe this stuff is not for him. I also say in the next line "For the other one integrate" ...I suppose that's a huge hint, too.